# fscanf and assigning a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

Why the following code does not assign any value to the 2D array elements? It reads the data from file; x is assigned with the correct values each time, but the 2D array, X is zero which is the value when it is initialized. The array allocated by malloc and I am using gcc (GNU). Here is part of the code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<omp.h>

#define N_mon     868// number of monomer per chain.
#define N_seg     N_mon/segm //number of segments per chain.
#define N_f2      511 // number of frames after.  
#define s1        500 
#define s2        1000
int main (void)
{
    FILE *finput1, *foutput1;
    char line1[140];
    float x=0., y=0., z=0., corang[N_f2]={0.0} ;
    int i=0, kk=0, ll=0, pid1=0, count=0, tot_count1=0, dt=0, cnt[N_f2]={0}, t=0;
    float **X;

    X=(float**)malloc(N_f2*sizeof(float*));
    for (i=0; i< N_f2; i++)
    {
        X[i]=(float*)malloc(N_mon*sizeof(float));
    }

    if ((finput1=fopen("./Stiff.vtf","r")) == NULL)
    {
         printf("Error: iutput file .vtf cannot be opened");
         return 0;
    }

    if ((foutput1=fopen("./msdr.dat","w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: output file msdr.dat cannot be opened");
        return 0;
    }

    for (ll=0; ll<N_f2; ll++)
        for (kk=0; kk<N_mon; kk++)
            X[ll][kk]=0.0;

    while(fgets(line1,120,finput1))
    {
        pid1=0;
        if(strncmp(line1,"timestep",8)==0)
        {
            if ( (count>=s1) && (count<s2) )
            {
                while (fscanf(finput1, "%f %f %f", &x,&y,&z) > 0)
                {
                    X[tot_count1][pid1]=x;
                    printf("x=%f and X=%f \n", x, X[tot_count1][pid1]);
                    pid1++;  
                }
                tot_count1++;
            }
            count++;
        } // if timestep
    } //while loop
// MSDs
    for (t=0;t<tot_count1-1;t++)
    {
        for (dt=1;(t+dt)<tot_count1;dt++)
        {
            cnt[dt]++;  // number of origins for interval length dt  
            for (i=0;i<N_mon;i++)
            {
                corang[dt]  += (X[t+dt][i] - X[t][i])*(X[t+dt][i] - X[t][i]);
            }
        }
    }

  //now msdx.....
    for (t=0;t<tot_count1-1;t++)
    {
        corang[dt]  /= cnt[t]?(N_mon*cnt[t]):1;
        fprintf(foutput1,"%d  %f \n",t, corang[dt]);
    }

    fclose(finput1);
    fclose(foutput1);

    for (i=0; i<N_f2; i++) free((void*)X[i]);
        free((void*)X);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Could you try to swap these two lines ? `pid1++;
              printf("x=%f and X=%f \n", x, X[tot_count1][pid1]);`

Comment: @francis, sorry, that was a copy paste problem, I do not have this `printf` in real code. Still the array values are zero. I will check the code again; the lines before this part and I will update the question.

Comment: What is the format of your input file?  Is it correct that you read from file in both the `fgets` and `fscanf` lines?

Comment: @simonc, the file (a simulation output) has some text which I should exclude them, and the rest are some numbers (coordinates, velocities and so on) I should read it based on time scale, i.e. from frame 100 to 500. I have used the first `fgets` to keep reading the file and the `fscanf` to extract the data. I am sure this is not the best way to do this.

Comment: You should check that `fscanf` returns exactly 3, or set `y` and `z` to some default value just before `fscanf`, in case input file has invalid number of numbers. Additionally, mixing `fgets` and `fscanf` can lead to unexpected problems. Using only `fgets` and then `sscanf` on the lines read is usually easier to get to work right. Or if you don't care about newlines, use `fscanf` only.

Comment: @hyde, thank you for the recommendation; I have changed my code. 
The problem is the output data on our local cluster are corrupted due to the cluster storage problem; some lines are OK but most of the lines are empty or less data than expected by the code.

Comment: Dear all, Thank you very much indeed for all your help and instructive recommendation. The problem is the output data on our local cluster are corrupted due to the cluster storage problem; some lines are OK but most of the lines are empty or less data than expected by the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because **I replaced `finput1` with `stdin` and `foutput1` with `stdout`** (part of forming [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is your work, not mine) **and ran it, and your code doesn't reproduce the faults you describe**: [here's proof](http://ideone.com/FAFuO0).